# Position items in a grid area

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm making an editor app with a layout like google sheet or any simple web app with a thin, screenwide toolbar in the top and other stuff below. But... I'm having problem to position items in the toolbar. I plan to place:

- a logo in the left corner
- something in the middle
- two buttons on the right side with specific order (like button A and B where B is closer to the right edge of the screen)

And most importantly i want to position these items **inside the toolbar to be vertically in the center**.

I tried so many things, but nothing really worked, except the very basic grid system below in which i want to place the items:

```css
.layout {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 34% 33% auto;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "toolbar toolbar toolbar"
    "searchbox resultbox editorbox";
}

.toolbar {
  grid-area: toolbar;
}

.searchbox {
  grid-area: searchbox;
}

.resultbox {
  grid-area: resultbox;
}

.manju-editor {
  grid-area: editorbox;
}
```

Can you pls tell me how could i position items the above described way?

Edit: per request the HTML also added, the app is created with create-react-app, so the html is its standard index.html and app is "assigned" to the root:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

render method from app.js:

```
  <div className={userSession.layout.name}>
    {userSession.layout.toolbar.active && <div className="toolbar">
      {this.generateComponents("toolbar")}
    </div>}
    {userSession.layout.search.active && <div className="searchbox">
      search
    </div>}
    {userSession.layout.results.active && <div className="resultbox">
      result
    </div>}
    {userSession.layout.editor.active && <div className="editor">
      editor
    </div>}
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you include a jsfiddle or gist that includes the html you're using as well? It would help to see the full context of the problem.

Comment: including the markup would help.

Comment: Thanks, edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```css
/* 
 * containing div, position is relative, set the div height here 
 */

.toolbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

/* 
 * all 3 children have absolute positioning
 */

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  /* center the element */
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the effort i tried it, but didn't work. Things not arranged to side (like the .right to the right), also the toolbar height is set by _grid-template-rows_.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer. It's [here](https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center-flexbox) and working :)